# Visual Studio project from 2015 became slow in VS 2017 debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project created with Visual Studio 2015. It is pretty fast when debugging in Visual Studio 2015 but very slow when debugging with Visual Studio 2017. Meanwhile, every project built with VS 2017 debug is fast. This has been going on for a while now.

I have deleted folders in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files** the issue still remains.
I also tried deleting

Answer (score 0):

After several days with this issue, was able to fix the issue by deleting .vs (formerly created by visual studio 2015) folder in the project's folder and rebuild.